# Campo input resultado NaN

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function id(el) {
  return document.getElementById( el );
}
function altura( un, quanti_imagens ) {
  return parseFloat(un.replace(',', '.'), 10) / parseFloat(quanti_imagens.replace(',', '.'), 10);
}
window.onload = function() {
  id('passo').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var result = altura( this.value , id('quanti_imagens').value );
    id('altura').value = String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney();
  });

  id('quanti_imagens').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var result = altura( id('passo').value , this.value );
    id('altura').value = String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney();
  });
}

String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
  var v = this;

  if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
  }

  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

  return v;


};
```

Está no Arquivo PHP (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). Funciona perfeitamente.

Valor do *input* `passo` / pelo "Passo" o valor pelo *input* `quanti_imagens`, porém está aparecendo `NaN` até o preenchimento dos dois campos de entrada.

Como faço para eliminar isso?

Comment: Inclua o html, os elementos com os ids "passo" e "quanti_imagens" são um inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque um ternário no `return v;` verificando se o primeiro caractere de `v` é um número:

```
return isNaN(v[0]) ? '' : v;
```

Porque se o valor de `v` for `NaN`, o valor em altura será vazio, caso contrário retornará o resultado da divisão em `v`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function id(el) {
  return document.getElementById( el );
}

function altura( un, quanti_imagens ) {
  return parseFloat(un.replace(',', '.'), 10) / parseFloat(quanti_imagens.replace(',', '.'), 10);
}

window.onload = function() {
  id('passo').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var result = altura( this.value , id('quanti_imagens').value );
    id('altura').value = String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney();
  });

  id('quanti_imagens').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var result = altura( id('passo').value , this.value );
    id('altura').value = String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney();
  });
}

String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
  var v = this;

  if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
  }

  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
  v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

  return isNaN(v[0]) ? '' : v;

};
```

```html
Passo:
<br>
<input id="passo">
<br>
Quantidade:
<br>
<input id="quanti_imagens">
<br>
Altura:
<br>
<input id="altura" disabled>
```

Comment: GRANDEEE SAM !! Muitissimo obrigado !! Deu certo !! Sucesso.
Sou leigo em PHP...rsrsrs